# Google push notifications for xamarin forms

Tags: c#-4.0, xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin forms and started work on google push notification. I am building application for iOS and android. Please help me how i should use this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are referring to Google Cloud Messaging. See https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Here's a walkthrough for using push notifications on Xamarin.Android:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote_notifications_in_android/

To get GCM notification on iOS take a look at:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Google.iOS.GoogleCloudMessaging

To get cross platform push notifications you can look at PushSharp:
https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp 
http://redth.codes/pushsharp-3-0-the-push-awakens/

Good luck!